# ActiveRecord: Find through multiple instances

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Say I have the following in my controller:

```
@category1
@category2
```

and I want to find all stores associated with those two categories...

```
@stores = @category1.stores + @category2.stores
```

this *does* work, but unfortunately returns an unaltered Array, rather than a AR::Base Array, and as such, I can't do things like pagination, scope, etc...

It seems to me like there's a built-in way of finding through multiple instance association... isn't there?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having trouble doing something very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930587/sql-union-creating-array-rather-than-activerecordrelation

Answer (score 0):

```
#@stores = @category1.stores + @category2.stores
#if you want to call API methods you can just add conditions with the category id
@stores = Store.find(:all, :conditions => ['category_id=?', a || b])
```

Comment: I can't do that, because the stores have many categories, and are associated through a join table

Answer (score 0):

With ActiveRecord, whenever you're finding a set of unique model objects, calling `find` on that model is usually your best bet.

Then all you need to do is constrain the join table with the categories you care about.

```
@stores = Store.all(:joins => :categories,
                    :conditions => ['category_stores.category_id in (?)', [@category1.id, @category2.id]])
```